# MATLAB: gscatter when there might be markers with the same coordinates

Tags: matlab

I have something very similar to this car data:

```
load carsmall  
gscatter(Displacement,Horsepower,Model_Year)
```

[image: Car scatterplot]

Let's say that in addition to the 1970 car down the bottom left with the value (85,46) I have another data point, which is a 1976 car which also has the value (85,46).

I'd be hoping to find some way of displaying it like the following, where the marker has become half red and half green, but the legend has remained unaltered. Can this, or some similar solution, be achieved in gscatter?

[image: Car scatterplot altered]

Comment: You can add a small random value to each coordinate. This is a common way of separating overlapping points.